# Add groovy extention module in runtime

Tags: groovy

I writing gradle plugin for code generation, and it's use groovy org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule. 
But extensions resolve on gradle (daemon) start stage, and add jar with META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule into build script classpath has no effect.

How to register ExtentionModule manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can, [as it says in the documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_extension_modules_and_classpath):

> to use an extension, it has to be available on classpath, as compiled classes, before the code using it gets compiled

Comment: I found workaround, if create my own classloader and load all my classes and groovy in it, all my extension initialize correctly.